# mysql order by IN clause maximum matches

Tags: mysql, sql

**Mysql Query**

```
select t.text from topic t 
inner join tag tg on tg.topic_id = t.id where tg.id in (3,4,5,6,7)
```

Now how can I order these results from maximum to minimum values matched in IN clause.

**update** - 
Between for those who suggested to add `order by tg.id desc` - Please don't misunderstand it orders by individual value of the tag id not by the number of  values matched in IN clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should JOIN your table with a grouped by `topic_id` set from the `tag` table like this:

```
select t.text from topic t 
inner join
 (SELECT topic_id, COUNT(id) tags_count
   FROM tag WHERE id IN (3,4,5,6,7)
   GROUP BY topic_id
 ) tg on tg.topic_id = t.id
ORDER BY tg.tags_count DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select t.text from topic t 
inner join tag tg on tg.topic_id = t.id where tg.id in (3,4,5,6,7)
order by tg.id desc
```